# keep composer 1 & 2 both in same machine

Tags: php, composer-php, multiple-versions

How we can use composer 1 & composer 2 both in the same machine.
As a developer we worked on the multiple project in the same machine and situation comes where project 1 required composer 1 and project 2 required compower version 2.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In this case you better ask your question first like `How to keep composer 1 & 2 both in same machine?` and then add your answer and accept it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i will follow the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I used to have composer 1 & 2 both in the same machine. I am hoping this will helpful for someone, who want to use composer 1 & 2 both as separate command

Keep Composer 1 & 2 as separate command

Setup Composer 1:

1. Copy the current composer directory to new

   ```
   cp `which composer` /usr/local/bin/composer1
   ```
2. Update it to version 1:

   ```
   composer1 self-update --1
   ```

Upgrade to Composer 2 & create alias:

1. Update composer to version 2

   ```
   composer self-update --2
   ```
2. Create symlink for composer2 (optional)

   ```
   ln -s `which composer` /usr/local/bin/composer2
   ```

Now you can use `composer` or `composer2` command for the project dependent on composer 2 and `composer1` command for the project have dependency on composer 1.

Note: you might required to use sudo before the command

Answer (score 0):

### for windows do the following steps:

- [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yclfs.png) ->   (create `composer1` directory in C:\composer_path)
- [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUKGS.png)  ->  (copy three file in `composer` directory to `composer1` directory)
- [three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCIIW.png)  ->  (set path `composer1` to `environment variable`)
- [four](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWovG.png)   -> (run `composer1 self-update --1` in cmd) because Convert to version 1.0.0
- [five](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX2bI.png) -> (test versions composer)

and Done! ^_^

you can see two version of composer installed in one windows system.

reference : [How to install two composer in one windows system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75258393/how-to-install-two-composer-in-one-windows-system)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33727956)

Comment: 2.5.1 is _not_ the composer LTS version, the LTS version is on the 2.2 channel. And honestly I see no need to duplicate your own answer as the comlete Q&A is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75268693/367456 and also prominently linked as related question already. Please remove it and improve the original answer.