# How to install two composer in one windows system?

Tags: windows, composer-php

How to install two composer in one windows system? (how to use difference composer in one windows system)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [keep composer 1 & 2 both in same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65273012/keep-composer-1-2-both-in-same-machine)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is there any good reason to use multiple Composer versions?

Comment: hi @NicoHaase . If you want the truth, I wanted to handle the dependencies of several projects with different versions of PHP with Composer, and I don't need to change the PHP path in `env variables` every time for each project.

 But until now, I could not install another version of PHP on my `Composer1` ! If it is not possible to install another version of PHP on `Composer1`, then my work is useless! 

Do you have a solution to install another version of Php on the second composer?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Usually, you can run Composer with any PHP version, it doesn't have to match the one your application uses

Comment: @NicoHaase Does composer version2.5.1 support php7.2.5 ?!!!!

Comment: See https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md: "Composer in its latest version requires PHP 7.2.5 to run"; the current latest version is indeed 2.5.1 and I see no problem in using that on PHP 7.2.5. Otherwise, feel free to use v2.2 which even works with PHP 5.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### for windows do the following steps:

- [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yclfs.png) ->   (create `composer1` directory in C:\composer_path)
- [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUKGS.png)  ->  (copy three file in `composer` directory to `composer1` directory)
- [three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCIIW.png)  ->  (set path `composer1` to `environment variable`)
- [four](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWovG.png)   -> (run `composer1 self-update --1` in cmd) because Convert to version 1.0.0
- [five](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX2bI.png) -> (test versions composer)

and Done! ^_^

you can see two version of composer installed in one windows system.

Comment: Congrats. Here a tip: Instead of 1.10.x use 2.2.x (or at least try with your new great setup). It's LTS and much faster (most of composer 1 plugins you don't need any longer with it, too, so you can easily get rid of them, too).

Comment: "this version latest version of support to php 7.2.5" - what do you mean by this? Composer 2.5.1 still supports PHP 7.2.5

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the windows installer *only*, IIRC you can't as it ships with the precondition to install under the canonical `composer` name.

However if you download the phar file, you just need to use the phar file of the version you would like to execute. This works independently to using the windows installer - both with and without it.

This has also the benefit that you can specify the PHP executable you would like to run `composer.phar` with.

```
c:\> c:\my\php.exe c:\my\composer-2.2.10.phar --version
```

This is basically what the Composer manual means where-ever it writes `php composer.phar ...`.

You replace `php` with the PHP executable you would like to use and `composer.phar` with the composer phar you would like to use.

The windows setup installer is just installing the latest with the PHP version on your system under the canonical name `composer`.  But instead you can create your own `composer.bat`.

You can then also create two such files for the different versions, e.g. `composer-blue.bat` and `composer-red.bat`.

This technique should be compatible to have *next* to `composer` with the windows setup installer, so you can use it to install one version you manage with the setup and zero up to N versions you manage yourself with the phar files.

- Composer homepage lists all composer.phar files, see https://getcomposer.org/download/ and scroll down to "Manual Downloads" section.
- A command-line utility like `wget` which also runs on Windows can greatly help you to streamline your process downloading the composer version of your choice under the file-name you'd like to have.
- There is a [Wikibook available on Windows Batch Scripting](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting).

Comment: tnks for answer. but What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: What about downloading the composer phar and then run it with the PHP command, e.g. `php composer.phar --version` from the directory where you downloaded it to see if you can get it running? Sounds like a good idea?

Comment: tanks @hakre . I resolved. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

**What I did was as follows:**

1. install a new php version on new folder suppose the new version is 7.3
2. in the 7.3 folder just copy the `php.exe` and past it with a new name `php73.exe` this will let you use php 7 using the command php73 any where
3. add the folder to your windows path
4. composer bin folder is installed in C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup
   just copy the bin folder and past it with name bin73
5. inside bin73 rename composer.bat to composer730.bat
6. edit composer730.bat file change the `php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*` to `php730 "%~dp0composer.phar" %*`
7. add C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin73 to your windows path

now you can use `composer73 install` for php 7 folders and `composer install` for your default php. As will you can use `php73 ...` for php 7 and `php ...` for your default php